# Number of ways to select subsets from a set of equal elements that have difference between partitions as 0

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am struggling with a combinatorics problem, which I understand but can't formulate a solution for.

**Problem statement:**

You are given a set of $n$ elements all of which have equal value. For example : $A = \{5,5,5,5,5\}$ where $n=5$.

You have to count the number of ways to select subsets from the original set such **that the subsets can be partitioned with the difference of 0**. ie. the sum of the left hand side should equal sum of the right hand side. For example: $\{5,5\}$ or $\{5,5,5,5\}$ these two can both be sub divided into sets that have equal partitions ($\{5,5\}, \{5,5\}$).

But the catch is that I have to calculate all the ways of obtaining the sum : example a valid set is $\{a_1, a_2\}$ ($a_1$ and $a_2$ are just indexes of the original set) which might look like $\{5,5\}$, but there are also many other valid sets that look the same ie. I include $\{a_2,a_3\}$ or $\{a_1,a_3\}$ *they all look the same* ie. $\{5,5\}$. **So how do I count that ?**

**What I have tried:**

I know the subsets that will be in the solution will only contain even number of elements, and I know that any one side of a solution subset cannot be $\ge n/2$.

So for every even number from 2 to $n/2$ you calculate the number of ways that much of elements can be selected. For example: for the subset of 4 elements we select the number of ways 2 elements can be selected = $5\choose 2$ * 2 (multiplied by 2 for the second half)

I don't know if the above is correct but it is infeasible to do when $n$ is large : is there a one -line expression for this. This my reasoning correct ?

Comment: It would be much easier to follow what you are doing if you make $A=\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$ and ask about subsets that have the same number of members.  Then instead of $a_1$ we can talk about $1$.  Now if your original subset is $\{1,2,3,4\}$ you want to divide that into two sets with two elements each.  Do we just count $\{1,2,3,4\}$ because it can be split, or do we count the three ways to divide it, or do we count the six ordered ways to divide it, so $\{1,2\},\{3,4\}$ is different from $\{3,4\},\{1,2\}$

Answer (score 0):

As you say you need each subset to have an even number of elements, so $n$ must be divisible by $4$.  Assuming $4$ divides $n$ you are just looking for half the number of even size subsets of $n$ items.  The half comes because splitting $\{a_1,a_2\}$ and $\{a_3,a_4\}$ is the same as splitting $\{a_3,a_4\}$ and $\{a_1,a_2\}$.  You might also want to subtract $1$ if you don't all the split of the empty set and the whole set.  Can the empty set be partitioned this way?  I think so, but some would disagree.  In that case you are looking for $$\frac 12\sum_{i=0}^{n/2}{n \choose 2i}=2^{n-2}$$
because half the $2^n$ subsets of a set with $n$ members have an even number of members

Comment: N does not need to be divisible by 4. My example shows 5 elements. Also why do you have 2i in your answer? What does that mean? And how does the summation expression equal a power of 2. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I thought you were partitioning the original set into two, each of which had to be able to be split, which is where the multiple of $4$ comes from.  If you just want to extract one subset that can be split, you just need to extract a subset that has an even number of elements.  That is half the total of $2^n$ subsets, so $2^{n-1}$

Comment: The $2i$ is the number of elements in a subset, which is required to be even.